# How to find list comprehension in python code

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pygments

I want to find a list comprehension in python source code, for that I tried to use Pygments, but it didn't find the way to do that.

To be more specific, I want to do a function that recognize all the posible list comprehension. For example:

```
[x**2 for x in range(5)]

[x for x in vec if x >= 0]

[num for elem in vec for num in elem]

[str(round(pi, i)) for i in range(1, 6)]
```

This examples are obtained from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

It is also valid a solution with regular expression.

Thank you

Comment: Can you assume that all the list comprehensions in the source are syntactically correct?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) library to parse Python code into a syntax tree and then walk the parsed tree to look for `ListComp` expressions.

Here's a simple example which prints the line numbers at which list comprehensions were found in the Python code passed via stdin:

```
import ast
import sys

prog = ast.parse(sys.stdin.read())
listComps = (node for node in ast.walk(prog) if type(node) is ast.ListComp)
for comp in listComps:
    print "List comprehension at line %d" % comp.lineno
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) built-in module.

```
import ast

my_code = """
print("Hello")
y = [x ** 2 for x in xrange(30)]
"""

module = ast.parse(my_code)
for node in ast.walk(module):
    if type(node) == ast.ListComp:
        print(node.lineno)  # 3
        print(node.col_offset)  # 5
        print(node.elt)  # <_ast.BinOp object at 0x0000000002326EF0>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the search dialog to find regular expressions.  The regular expression I use is as follows:

```
(\=|\s|\=\s|\()\[.+for.+in.+\]
```

This will find list comprehensions and generators. For the examples you provided, I modified the expression as follows:

```
\[.+for.+in.+\]
```

However, the first expression is more complete as list comprehensions and generators are assigned to variables.